# Sum first N values in a Comma Separated List (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, split, sum, google-sheets-formula

Given the following conditions:

```
 A cell containing a Comma Separated List (Column B in table)

 A cell containing how many values to sum from the Comma Separated List (Column A in table)
```

Data

| MAX INDEX | COMMA SEPARATED LIST TO SUM | EXPECTED MATH | EXPECTED VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 | =1+2+3+4+5 | 15 |
| 3 | 5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50 | =5+10+15 | 30 |

image
[image]

I have seen formulas using OFFSET, but in application, OFFSET doesn't seem to work with a CS List (only an actual range).

Is there a formula that will sum up only the first N values in a Comma Separated List without using helper columns? (So the entirety of the operation will consist of only three cells...  MAX Index value, the Comma Separated List, and the output cell containing the formula).

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. Use [Markdown Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892)-all the data needed to answer your question must be in the question itself. [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: including an input table and a desired output table into the question helps future visitors.

Comment: @TheMaster Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by "table".  On another post, I gave a link to the file, and you said, "You should use a table".  This time, I included a picture of the table, and you said I still needed to use a table.  Can you please explain what you mean by "use a table"?

Comment: @RogueScientistAllen  Click the first link `Markdown Table` in my  first comment. Second see the edit @Osm made. Images are impossible to copy. Tables can be copied

Comment: Ahhh...  That helps!  I was under the impression that by a table, an image of the table was enough to view the issue.  Did not think about copy/paste (since this was so small)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/BYROW(
 IF(SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(SPLIT(B2:B, ",")))<=A2:A, SPLIT(B2:B, ","), ), 
 LAMBDA(xx, SUM(xx))))))
```

[image]

or alternative:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/
 BYROW(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B5&",", 
 BYROW(A2:A5, LAMBDA(xx, JOIN(, REPT("\d+,", xx))))), ",")), 
 LAMBDA(yy, SUM(yy))))))
```

[image]

or non-lambda alternative:

```
=FLATTEN(INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(SPLIT(B2:B, ",")))<=A2:A, SPLIT(B2:B, ","), )*1), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A))&")")))),2))
```

[image]

to quickly confuse noobs:

```
=INDEX(BYROW(BYROW(
 IF(SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(SPLIT(B2:B, ",")))<=
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX((A2:A<>"")*ROW(A2:A))), SPLIT(B2:B, ","), )*1, 
 LAMBDA(aa, JOIN("+", aa))), 
 LAMBDA(xx, INDEX(QUERY(, "select "&xx), 2))))
```

[image]

Comment: can you please explain a bit I didn't get `Index.../.../`

Comment: @Osm you mean `IFERROR(1/(1/` ?

Comment: Yes   @Player0 `IFERROR(1/(1/` if you can explain, I'll tast it later.

Comment: @Osm that's for removing zeros: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVb3d.png

Comment: Player0 you saying Im a noob huh

Comment: @Osm only if you got confused by the last one :)

Comment: Yeh for a second, even though i did nested `BYROW` before. Its the use of `INDEX` for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
=sum(array_constrain(split(B2, ","),1, A2))
```

Explanation:

- sum over
- a constrained array (of A2 columns and 1 row)
- formed by splitting the contents of B2 on `,`

Comment: One reason is the OP did not include a minimal example, and respondents responded in any case. When asked for a downvote reason, I was directed to this. [Am I still supposed to explain my downvotes or not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not) and this [Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr)

Comment: Fair I guess.  I find spreadsheets a horribly constrained programming environment and was just pleased with thinking of a quick solution, example or not.  In fairness to the OP they did try, even if it's a picture.  In any case votes are free.

Comment: @2e0byo Downvotes on answers aren't free. They cost 1 rep on the voter and 2 reps on the voted.

Comment: To clarify I asked for comment mostly because this isn't a bad answer :p   Or if it is I'd like to know wny. @TheMaster I meant in the sense of a 'free vote', i.e. what we call (bizarrely) 'unwhipped' in the uk.

Comment: @2e0byo Also, OP didn't try. The picture is what they want. What they tried is nothing or not shown. In any case, I think that shouldn't reflect on the answer post. I upvoted, because your answer is the simplest.

Comment: @2e0byo Handle empty cells; for the time being, it displays `0`.

Comment: Sorry.  In regards to "OP didn't try", I did try, I just didn't post the failed formulas, and explained that in the original posting (I had tried several variations of the OFFSET formula).  Perhaps I'm just not familiar with the "etiquette" here on what to post.  As for the examples, I only used a picture because there was no "live formulas" on that sheet, and have no experience posting raw data on here.  What you saw was exactly what was on my sheet.  Had I known that I was expected to include non-functioning formulas, I would have (just wasn't aware that was expected).

Comment: Thank you @2e0byo.  Looking at your formula, I shook my head, as when I was trying to figure it out, I think I actually think I said, "I need to find a way to limit the array to just what I need" (I mean, that's close to "ArrayConstrain".  Unfortunately, I had never had a reason to use that formula (until now), so it's possibility as a solution never really entered my mind.  But yeah, makes absolute sense ("Split the value, but limit the array to only the amount specified, and then add up the limited array".)  Now I feel dumb!

Comment: @RogueScientistAllen add `IF(A2="",,` like this `IF(A2="",,sum(array_constrain(split(B2, ","),1, A2)))` to eliminate `0`'s if input is empty if you need it.

Comment: @Osm empty cell handling wasn't speced so it's UB ;) But yes, an if is probably simplest.  Or even conditional formatting to remind you to fill it in....

Comment: @RogueScientistAllen UB means did't understand it

Comment: Thank you!  I ended up adding in two IF statements.  One if column B was blank, and one if column A was blank (Guess I could make that an IF(OR( statement, though).

Comment: @RogueScientistAllen Using this example of 2e0byo you can do it like this `=IF(OR(A2="",B2=""),,sum(array_constrain(split(B2, ","),1, A2)))`

Comment: @RogueScientistAllen the [4th formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73921454/5632629) will stop at C3 and not spill into C4. logic is the same (or even better) as having two IF statements

Answer (score 1):

**Use this**

```
=MAP(B2:B,A2:A, LAMBDA(rg,idx, IF(rg="",, ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(rg,", ",0),1,idx))))))
```

[image]

### Demo

[image]

Used formulas help
[**`MAP`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`IF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) - [**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`SUM`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669) - [**`SPLIT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)

Answer (score 0):

```
=MAP(
  A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),
  B2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(A2:A)),
  LAMBDA(a,b,
    QUERY(
      QUERY(SPLIT(b,","),
        "Select "&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("+","Col"&SEQUENCE(a))),0
      )
    ,"offset 1",0)
  )
)
```

`SPLIT` by comma, then use `QUERY` to do the addition. The addition string `Col1+Col2+..` is created dynamically using `JOIN`